# I want to make an input in the admin panel with which you can increase / decrease prices in several tables in db by %

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I want to make an input in the admin panel with which you can increase / decrease prices in several tables in db by %.
At the moment, I did it through a filter

```
    {
        return [
            new TwigSimpleFilter('price_kiev', [$this, 'formatPriceKiev'])
        ];
    }
    public function getPriceEditKiev()
    {
        $result =  DB::table('another_pricelist_edit')->select('price_edit_kiev')->where('id', 1)->first();
        return $result->price_edit_kiev;
    }
    public function formatPriceKiev($number)
    {
        $a =  $this->getPriceEditKiev();
        if ($a >= 1) {
            $price = $number + $number / 100 * $a;
            return round($price, -1);
        }else{
            return $number;
        }
    }
```

markup:

```
<td class="column-3">
{{ item.price_kiev_1 | price_kiev | number_format(0, '', ' ' ) }}</td>
```

admin panel with tables:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
input where I enter the number for the filter, which I want to remake in order to use it to change the prices in the table by a percentage:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

In short, how can I make an input in the admin panel with which I can update the prices in the tables in database?
maybe there are similar guides, I will be grateful

sql something like this:

```
update 
  table1 
set 
  table1.price = (price + price)/100 * input;
select 
  * 
from 
  table1;
```

where -> input: num %

Comment: please can you tell us more, like.. you want to change actual data in database tables OR you just want that data to be untouched and just want to show the user a data which is affected by percentage

Comment: i want to update actual data in db tables by 1 input and i doesnt know how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make one dedicated action and ajax handler in your controller.

1. action to render HTML
2. ajax handler to handle the request when you submit the form

**Note:** `Please change all the paths and the name according to your plugin`

> Add action and ajax handler `plugins/hardiksatasiya/so/controllers/Items.php`

```
class Items extends Controller
{
    // other code ....

    public function updateTable() {
        // we want to show our menu as active
        BackendMenu::setContext('HardikSatasiya.SO', 'main-menu-item-main', 'side-menu-item-update-items');
    }

    public function onUpdateTableAjax() {
        $value = post('update_value');

        if(!$value) {
            Flash::error("please enter value");    
            return;
        }

        // write your table with your logic
        Item::query()->update([
            'value' => \DB::raw("value * $value") 
             // please sanitize post input and use here we just used it here as demo
        ]);

        Flash::success("Successfuly updated tabel with value: $value");
    }

}
```

> Add HTML markup `plugins/hardiksatasiya/so/controllers/items/updatetable.htm`

```html
<form 
    class="form-elements" 
    data-request="onUpdateTableAjax" 
    data-request-flash
>
  <div class="form-group span-left">
      <label>Update Table</label>
      <input type="text" name="update_value" value="" class="form-control" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group span-left">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update Table</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Now you also need to show this action/html in frontend so the user can go there so we set menu item**

> update `plugins/hardiksatasiya/so/plugin.yaml` : `side-menu-item-update-items` <- we are adding this menu item

```
plugin:
    name: 'hardiksatasiya.so::lang.plugin.name'
    description: 'hardiksatasiya.so::lang.plugin.description'
    author: hardikSatasiya
    icon: oc-icon-star
    homepage: ''
navigation:
    main-menu-item-main:
        label: Items
        url: hardiksatasiya/so/items
        icon: icon-star
        sideMenu:
            side-menu-item-main:
                label: Items
                url: hardiksatasiya/so/items
                icon: icon-star
            side-menu-item-update-items:
                label: Settings
                url: hardiksatasiya/so/items/updatetable
                icon: icon-sliders
```

> Please check the video for the output result

[image]

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Just for clarification shouldn't `'value' => \DB::raw('value * 2')` be `'value' => \DB::raw("value * $value")`

Comment: yes absolutely ;) .. let me fix it

Comment: one more question, how can i add round to the nearest multiple of 10 to request I already have: `Clothes::query()->update ([ 'price_kiev_1' => \DB::raw("price_kiev_1 + price_kiev_1 / 100 * $value") ]);`

Comment: If you need to round to the nearest multiple of 10, you can divide your value by 10, then round as you want and then multiply the result by 10.